# How do I set up the visual studio android emulator?

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio, android-emulator

How do I set up the visual studio android emulator?

I would like to set this up on visual studio but there isn't much documentation on how to do this. Also, would I be able to run this with ReactNative?

Any tips or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You want to open android emulator from VS code right ?